# WCF Service "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a WCF service that is using wsHTTPBinding and when I make a call using my client test app at a certain point I get the error The remote server returned an unexpected response: `The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.`

The Binding config from my web.config for the service is as such:

```
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
```

And the endpoint on the service side:

```
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="WS_UCC_XML.IWS_UCC_XML" />
```

And the binding config in the client:

```
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IWS_UCC_XML_SSL" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: 1) It's likely a setting on the service side, not the client side.  2) Do you have an explicit endpoint defined in your service's config?  The binding definition in the config won't be used unless it's assigned to an endpoint.  Please post the complete `<system.serviceModel>` section of your **service's** config.

Comment: I added the endpoint configuration to the question.

Comment: Try setting a high limit for the `maxAllowedContentLength` attribute on the `<requestLimits>` element in system.webServer->security->reqestFiltering.  The bindings as defined look correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add the maxBufferSize="2147483647" parameter to the client and server binding tag in config:

```
<binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
```

Try also the MaxItemsInObjectGraph - add the following to the "system.serviceModel" section on server and client:

```
<commonBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
  </serviceBehaviors>
</commonBehaviors>
```